# Determining Goalie Stick Length

Tags: equipment, ice-hockey

As an ice hockey goalie, I find it a bit hard to determine the correct length for my stick while at the store.

I often find myself trying a few different lengths and even after buying it I'm questioning my decision. While I generally have never picked one that is absurdly longer or shorter that affects me during a game, I can't help but feel like I may at times have chosen incorrectly and could be putting myself at a slight disadvantage that could be affecting my posture and position.

Is there a way to determine what is a correct length or perhaps a "checklist" I should go through while at the store to make sure I've chosen a proper length for my stick?

Answer (score 7):

If it's that big of a deal for you, I'd bring my skates with me, to be honest. As a defenseman, I've just gotten used to the size I need, although it changes based on the manufacturer of the blade (some blades are taller than others and affect the overall height), but that bit of randomness isn't big enough to bother me.

I would think the biggest deal for you as a goalie would be the lie of the stick, and that shouldn't change once you've decided which fits you the best.